Setting parameters in a tool using values from a table
I have to run the Fuzzy Membership tool for more than forty different instances. Each instance has unique minimum and maximum values. Some have the same inputs and all have different outputs. I have created a table called Parameter Values with the necessary parameters listed in the following fields: Input Raster, Min Value, Max Value, Output Raster, and Run ID.
My current method uses Iterate Row Selection on the Parameter Values table. In the iterator window, I have selected Run_ID under the Group By Fields selection.
From here I am trying to get the parameters available to add into the Fuzzy Membership tool. I use the Calculate Value tool with the following expression: r"%Parameter_Values%.Input_Raster". The data types are set as Raster Dataset for the Input Raster and Output Raster fields. They are set as Double for the Min Value and Max Value fields.
From here I connect everything to the Fuzzy Membership tool. I can just select the variable in the drop-down box for input raster and the min/max values. I have to use inline variable substitution for the output.
However, I get errors when running the model. The Fuzzy Membership tool does not recognize the parameters. Does anyone have any advice for what I may have done wrong? I've attached an image of the model.


use the row iterator to step through your table, then use calculate value tool to create the fuzzy function and use inline variable substition to pass that into the fuzzy membership tool.

Thank you for the good feedback. I see the my original question was lacking clarity. I have updated and would appreciate any help you can offer!

can you add a screen shot of how you have set up the calculate value tool for your min or max value.

Please be more precise in detailing the errors that you are getting.  Please copy them in exactly and completely.
